# what does the + and the - symbols indicate when a "jobs" command is executed in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process

When I run the jobs command in CUI to check the jobs. I will get the result like below.

```
[4]-   Stopped  Passwd.
[5]+   Stopped  Cat > d1.
```

I didn't get, why `+` and `-` is used?

Can anyone explain me the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically this is specific to the shell you're using (which I suspect is `bash`), but as far as I know all shells assign the same meaning here, taken from venerable<sup>1</sup> `csh`: `+` is the "most current" job, the one that `fg` with no argument will resume, and `-` is the "previous" job.  When the "current" job finishes, the previous becomes the current.

You can also refer to these as `%+` and `%-`, in `fg` and `bg` commands, and use `%-` and `%+` as commands (and `%` with no argument, or `%%`, means the same as `%+`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Or some other less flattering adjective. :-)